# mongodb3.0 can not run with my config file

Tags: mongodb

this is my config file

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: "D:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\3.0\data\\log\\mongodb.log"
    logAppend: true
    verbosity: 1
storage:
    engine: wiredTiger
    journal:
        enabled: true
    dbPath: "D:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\3.0\\data\\db"
    logPath: "D:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\3.0\\data\\log\\mongodb.log"
    directoryPerDB: true 
    wiredTiger: 
        engineConfig: 
            cacheSizeGB: 2
processManagement:
   fork: true
   windowsService: 
       serviceName: MongoDB
       displayName: MongoDB
       description: "MongoDB server version 3.0"
       serviceUser: ********
       servicePassword: *******
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27017
   http: 
       enabled: true
setParameter:
   enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
#vim:ft=yaml
```

my os is windows 8.1 64bit.wen i start the mongod.exe  but error!
this is my command

```
>mongod -f "D:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\etc\mongodb.conf"
```

this is error message

```
D:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin>mongod -f "D:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\etc\mongodb.conf"
2015-03-29T13:09:27.379+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory D:\data\db\ not found., terminating
2015-03-29T13:09:27.380+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

can you help me analysis where is the wrong?
thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "\"D:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin\mongod.exe\" --service --config=\"D:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\etc\mongodb.conf\" --dbpath=\"D:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\data\db\""  DisplayName= "MongoDB" start= "auto"
```

must add the  --dbpath     config when starting

```
mongod --config "D:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\etc\mongodb.conf" --dbpath "D:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\data\db"
```